# Тип  речи в тексте

Tags: стилистика, учебное-задание

Как определить тип  речи в тексте (повествование, описание, рассуждение) или с элементами?

> Прекрасен лес в зимнее пушкинское утро. Что может сравниться с лазурной синевой безоблачного неба в ясный зимний рассвет?
>
> Бездонная голубизна, царящая на небесах, веет радостью и красотой на землю, покрытую искрящейся, сверкающей белизной снега, лишь кое-где перечеркнутую слегка засыпанными полосками следов. Какое разнообразие! Одни из них похожи на тонкое кружево, забытое клёстами, другое (непонятно что "другое", наверное ошибка в сочинении, нужно "другие") - на затейливый ковер, вытканный зайцем-непоседой.
>
> Величественные ели обступают пришельца, словно просят полюбоваться их белоснежными одеждами, а березки, ветви которых покрыты резной изморозью, предлагают оценить их воздушный наряд. Чуть тронь их, и на тебя обрушится звенящий дождь снежинок. Присмотрись, поймай несколько на руку и ты увидишь как они красивы. Вот пушистая звездочка, вот мягкий шар, а вот, не похожие ни на что, кроме изобретательной фантазии русского кудесника, необыкновенные снежинки.
>
> Блестят и искрятся на солнце свисающие с веток сосульки. Невозможно оторвать глаз от этой фантастической красоты ясного зимнего утра.
>
> Жалко расставаться с удивительной сказкой леса, но пора, пора... Прощай, лес, прощай, сказка! До новой встречи.

Текст фактически не разбит на абзацы, т.к. я запуталась в количестве ССЦ. Сначала я думала, что это просто описание, но потом задумалась, не будет ли оно с элементами рассуждения, как никак риторические вопросы, восклицания. Вроде бы есть начальный тезис, который потом доказывается, пусть и с помощью описаний, и заключительная часть текста тоже подтверждает основной тезис высказывания, жду предложений.

Answer (score 2):

Как всё это условно!
*Растёт под моим окном берёза. Зимой ветки её опушены инеем, серебрящимся в лучах низкого зимнего солнца. Весной на этих ветках лопаются почки и появляются пушистые нежные зелёные листочки. Летом ветер запутывается в её пышной кроне. Осенью моя береза радует глаз золотым нарядом.*

Вот такой условный  текст. Сколько слайдов к нему можно сделать? И очень интересно, к какому типу речи его можно отнести?

**Дополнение** (к комментарию Людмилы).
  А почему не рассуждение? Ведь есть тезис, а дальше доказывается, что береза действительно стоит. )))
   Я ж и говорю, что это всё условно. Про слайды-картинки - это вообще для начальной школы. Имхо, все эти теории о построении текстов, может, и нужны, но если только  на этапе обучения. И, видимо, необходимы, для научного, делового стилей. Но тексты художественной литературы каждый строит по каким-то другим, своим внутренним, законам. Нет в ней ни чистых описаний, ни тем более рассуждений.  И я честно не знаю, к какому типу речи отнести мой текст про берёзу. Кстати, и построен он не канонически: вывода-то нет. А, между тем, все три типа его требуют. А в этом тексте какой вывод может быть? Я его придумать не смогла. Мне и без него текст показался законченным.

Comment: Описание с элементами повествования.Или повествование с элементами описания. А Ваше мнение -  чистое описание? Я не увидела ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Комментарий не поместился. Я дополнила свой вопрос.))))

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, рассуждение с элементами описания.Есть тезис, доказательства с примерами, ясна позиция автора. Но и описание тоже есть.

Comment: тоже так думала...однако...при описании композиция текста такая: 1 часть - общие сведения о предмете ( у меня "Красив лес зимним утром") 2 часть - отдельные признаки предмета речи ( у нас это "следы, ели, березы, снежинки, сосульки") 3 часть авторская оценка, вывод, заключение ( и у нас это тоже есть "Какая красота! Не хочется прощаться с сказкой" ) Вот композиция типичного описания..... ну так сюда никакое рассуждение не укладывается

Comment: Где это Вы нашли? Композиция сочинения - описания - да, но типы речи в соч.-описании могут быть разные.Общие сведения о предмете, авторская оценка, вывод, заключение - никак не типичное описание,это типичное рассуждение, особенно 3 часть. Вот 2- описание. Описание - если описываемое можно снять на 1 слайд и рассмотреть детали,повествование - на много слайдов (каждое действие), рассуждение нельзя сфотографировать, это речь. Посмотрите, сколько здесь речи, которую не сфотографируешь!